# pg8000.core.ProgrammingError: 'could not determine data type of parameter $2'

Tags: postgresql, pg8000

I'm using pg.8000 (Postgres) and trying to run the following `SELECT` query

```
cursor.execute(
        """
        SELECT orders.name, orders.order_price, orders.selling_price, orders.earnings
        FROM member, orders
        WHERE member.id=orders.member_id
        AND member.name = %s
        """,
        member_username
    )
```

Where `member.username` is a String.

But I am  getting the following error.

> pg8000.core.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', 'ERROR', '42P18', 'could not determine data type of parameter $2', 'postgres.c', '1350', 'exec_parse_message', '', '')

However, when I run same query using GUI tool, everything runs fine and I get the results. What is the problem?

Comment: What is in `member_username`?

Comment: a String which I'm passing...

Comment: I mean maybe it's empty or not correct string. Did you check it?

Comment: Yes I've checked that, and it's ok...

Comment: I found it is about to parsing that string...so I found a solution but still confused why it is happening. 
Here the case when it works:

`cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT orders.name, orders.order_price, orders.selling_price, orders.earnings
            FROM member, orders
            WHERE member.id = orders.member_id
            AND member.name = '{}'
            """.format(member_username)
        )`

Comment: In this case, you give only a string in `cursor.execute` without params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the parameter wrong, you should give a tuple, a list or a dictionary

Example with a tuple:

```
cursor.execute(
        """
        SELECT orders.name, orders.order_price, orders.selling_price, orders.earnings
        FROM member, orders
        WHERE member.id=orders.member_id
        AND member.name = %s
        """,
        (member_username,)
    )
```

Example with a list:

```
cursor.execute(
        """
        SELECT orders.name, orders.order_price, orders.selling_price, orders.earnings
        FROM member, orders
        WHERE member.id=orders.member_id
        AND member.name = %s
        """,
        [member_username]
    )
```

Example with a dictionary:

```
cursor.execute(
        """
        SELECT orders.name, orders.order_price, orders.selling_price, orders.earnings
        FROM member, orders
        WHERE member.id=orders.member_id
        AND member.name = %(mname)s
        """,
        {'mname' : member_username}
    )
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: Yeah, that is why! Thanks!